# In d3 4.0, how can I get extra data from the stratified object?

Tags: d3.js

I'm a new to D3 also stackoverflow, and have some question.

```
[
{"id": "1",  "name": "Eve",         "parent": "" , "txt": "text1."},
{"id": "2",  "name": "Cain",        "parent": "1", "txt": "text2."},
{"id": "3",  "name": "Seth",        "parent": "1", "txt": "text3."},
{"id": "4",  "name": "Enos",        "parent": "3", "txt": "text4."},
{"id": "5",  "name": "Noam",        "parent": "3", "txt": "text5."},
{"id": "6",  "name": "Abel",        "parent": "1", "txt": "text6."},
{"id": "7",  "name": "Awan",        "parent": "1", "txt": "text7."},
{"id": "8",  "name": "Enoch",       "parent": "7", "txt": "text8."},
{"id": "9",  "name": "Azura",       "parent": "1", "txt": "text9."}
];
```

Above is array object which is not stratified yet.

below is the stratified result and code.

```
var stratify = d3.stratify()
              .id(function(d){ return d.id; })
              .parentId(function(d){ return d.parent; });
```

[stratified object](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/master/img/stratify.png)

I want to use the data object, like below code

```
node.append("text")
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

but, above doesn't work.

refered to https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md#stratify
and I edited the array object a little.

thanks & best regards. and It would be greatly appreciated if you could give me a feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the answer.

```
return d.data.name
```

what an embarrassingly amateurish thing...